# How to clone from github from behind corporate proxy

Tags: windows, git, github

I am behind a corporate proxy that is pretty annoying:

1. The actual proxy address used is determined by a script
2. It requires authentication
3. It *replaces* the certificates of web pages using HTTPS

How to successfully clone a github repository in this scenario?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The first issue is not really related to git - it's more that it is a necessary step to be able to actually configure the proxy.
   The proxy configuration on a windows computer can be found at Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN settings.
   If "Use automatic configuration script" is checked, you first need to download the specified file and open it. I got a file containing a small script. It looked something like this:

   ```
   function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
   {
       var myip = myIpAddress();
       var hostip = dnsResolve(host);
       if (isInNet(hostip,"192.168.0.0","255.255.0.0"))
           return "DIRECT";
       if (isInNet(hostip,"xyz.abc.0.0","255.255.0.0"))
           return PROXY special-proxy:8080;
       return "PROXY default-proxy:8080";
   }
   ```

   So, in my case, the proxy to use was `default-proxy:8080`.
2. To actually get git to use the proxy, I had to use `git config --global http.proxy http://<domain>\<username>:<password>@default-proxy:8080`.

   The obvious downside to this is that you will have your domain password stored as plain text on the hard disk.

   Other settings didn't work, although different sources claim they should. Those were:

   1. Setting the environment variables `https_proxy` or `http_proxy` to `http://<domain>\<username>:<password>@default-proxy:8080`
   2. Setting the global git config to that value: `git config --global https.proxy http://<domain>\<username>:<password>@default-proxy:8080`
   3. Setting the environment variable `http_proxy` to `http://<domain>\<username>:<password>@default-proxy:8080`
3. To get around the third issue, the simplest possibility is to ignore the certificate errors by setting an environment variable - the certificates returned by the proxy aren't worth anything anyway:

   ```
   set GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
   ```

---

To not store the plain password in the git config, you can use a local proxy instead, e.g. [cntlm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm).

It allows to store a password hash instead. To get the hash, use this command:

```
cntlm.exe -H -d <domain> -u <username>
```

After that, you will be prompted for your password. The result will be a list of three hashes, of which `PassNTLMv2` most likely is the relevant one in this scenario. Replace the `Password` line in the cntlm.ini with the line from the output, including the `PassNTLMv2` part.

Obviously, you have to configure git to use this local proxy instead, now.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only solution that worked! I did not know that the auto config script would be downloaded as a file. One thing I should mention - if the hash character (#) appears anywhere in <username>:<password> it will not work, as git will interpret everything past it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want write access to github you will have to be able to get ssh access to github through the proxy.
To do this, you can use `corkscrew`.

In short this is how you do this:
First unpack [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/)
Then create a file in `~/.ssh/proxy_auth` which contains `<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>`
Now tell ssh to use corkscrew to access `github.com` through the proxy by adding the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
host github.com
    port 22
    proxycommand corkscrew <proxy_ip_address> <proxy_port> %h %p ~/.ssh/myauth
```

Now test if ssh can get through the proxy by `ssh -T git@github.com`.  If this works, the `git:/` protocol should also be able to get through the proxy.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just push with http?

Comment: No idea, I was only able to push through my corporate proxy over the ssh protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set proxy every time you try to clone something behind the corporate proxy server, try looking for ".*bashrc*" file in your home directory and set it. From next time, you won't have to set it up manually.

If your proxy server is set as below:

```
Server: myproxyserver
Port: 8080
Username: mydomain\myusername
Password: mypassword
```

in the .bashrc file, set the following:

```
set HTTP_PROXY="http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080"
set HTTPS_PROXY="http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080"
```